# Azure logic app setup credentials sftp+azure vault

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I have created a SFTP connector which works like a trigger as below. I have an azure vault with certificate. How do I pass the authentication in SFTP for Azure Vault. Pls help.

[image: Trigger is when file arrives]

[image: SFTP connection details]

Comment: You can’t, it’s a connection.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest an approach as the trigger is an sftp "when a file arrives"

Comment: The approach is to enter the credentials. Simple!

Comment: But we cannot as this is restricted by company security, also these has to retrive from Azure vault. A similar example is mentioned here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43244#issuecomment-578346024

Comment: I am trying to implement this

Comment: As I said, you can't.  It's a connection.  It's persisted and it's not possible to use KeyVault credentials.

Comment: ok understood, but the security is not allowing to pass just the credential instead a key via azure vault. Does it mean this isnt achievable in any way?

Comment: Yes, it is not achievable @piku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "I have created a SFTP connector" - I suppose you created it manually. If you want the parameter values (SSH private key, etc.) to be retrieved from a key vault, you need to deploy your SFTP connector using an [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#arm-template-resource-definition) and a [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files).

You can adjust your parameter file so that the secret values are taken directly from key vault secrets during deployment. This article explains the process in detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-powershell#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id

Comment: Hi @10 glad to see u after a decade! Thanks for the suggestion I find your answers always credible. I'm not aware of ARM template and not sure how to deploy this through yml pipelines

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I've been useful in the past. For ARM template deployments, you can take it step by step: first familiarize yourself with deployments from PowerShell e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment, then you can try creating a Release Pipeline with an "ARM template deployment" task, then you can try creating a YAML pipeline with an AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3